# Actualizar y eliminar un objeto dentro de un array de un store de Pinia en Vue

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js, pinia

Estoy haciendo un CRUD en Vue 3 y estoy usando **Pinia** para guardar mis objetos como un arreglo. Todo funciona bien pero ya cuando quiero actualizar uno de los objetos me aparece el error de:

> [Vue warn] Set operation on key "id" failed: target is readonly

> [Vue warn] Set operation on key "length" failed: target is readonly

En mi store defino mi arreglo de la siguiente manera:

```
const companies = ref<Company[]>([])
```

En mi composable ya que tengo el objeto con los datos actualizados guardados en **data.data** y el parámetro **id** que es un atributo del objeto intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
const { companies } = store
const index = companies.findIndex(c => c.id = id)
if(index > -1)
     companies.splice(index, 1, data.data)
store.setCompanies(companies)
```

Sin embargo, es en el método **splice** que me da este error, ya sea si lo quiero usar para reemplazar el objeto o para sacarlo del arreglo.
He visto que hay un método **store.$patch** pero no sé si aplique para este caso, y si quisiera aplicar un filter y luego reemplazar todo el arreglo a la larga que sean muchos objetos no lo veo conveniente.

Comment: Ha descrito lo que dice la documentación en cuanto al error de mutar un estado. Pero la solución es usar ``store.$patch((state) => { }``, entonces, la verdadera pregunta es: Cómo puede usar $patch sin tener que reemplazar todo el arreglo por que pueden ser muchos a largo plazo

Comment: -mutando el estado: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#usage-with-the-options-api